React with map and condition
I'm trying to create a column in data-grid react having various values ​​and wanting them to be written in different colors
written like this he writes them all in one color....
/* const category = params.data.categories?.map((cat) =>
      <div className="split2">
          <div>
              <font color="blue">{cat.category}</font>
          </div>

          <div class="clearer"> </div>
      </div> 
       );  */


/*  const category1 = params.data.categories?.map(cat => {
     if (cat.category == "TOPGAMES") {
         return (<div className="split2">
             <div>
                 <font color="blue">{cat.category}</font>
             </div>

             <div class="clearer"> </div>
         </div>);
     }



 });

*/
    params.data.categories?.map(cat => {

        if (cat.category == "TOPGAMES") {
            const categoria = <font color="blue">{cat.category}</font>;
            return (
                <div className="split2">
                         <div>
                             {categoria}
                         </div>
         
                         <div class="clearer"> </div>
                     </div>
              );   
        }
        if (cat.category == "CLASSICI") {
            const categoria = <font color="green">{cat.category}</font>;
            return (
                <div className="split2">
                         <div>
                             {categoria}
                         </div>
         
                         <div class="clearer"> </div>
                     </div>
              );
        }
        if (cat.category == "EXCLUSIVE") {
            const categoria = <font color="red">{cat.category}</font>;
            return (
                <div className="split2">
                         <div>
                             {categoria}
                         </div>
         
                         <div class="clearer"> </div>
                     </div>
              );
        } else {
            const categoria = <font>{cat.category}</font>;
            return (
                <div className="split2">
                         <div>
                             {categoria}
                         </div>
         
                         <div class="clearer"> </div>
                     </div>
              );
        }
    });

but i don't see anything in column of data-grid
i would like check cat.category and based on its value write it a color

You're trying to reference categoria outside the function where it was actually defined, that doesn't make any sense.
